# Does there exist an algorithm that outputs a maximum weight transversal and has a stable matching?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matching-theory

If you have some bipartite graph with an adjacency matrix that represents the weights of the edges of that particular bipartite graph, then the Hungarian algorithm outputs a maximum weight transversal. However if you would apply this to a marriage problem, where you have a bipartite graph with an equal amount of men and women that need to be paired with each other for marriage where the weights would represent the combined 'happiness/utility' between the pair, then when applying the Hungarian algorithm it will give you a maximized sum of these weights, but this matching will not guarantee to be a stable matching. Now I have found that there exists an algorithm called the Gale-Shapely algorithm that always finds a stable matching when you have an equal number of vertices in both classes of a bipartite graph. But if I understood it correctly, a stable matching does not have to mean that the sum of the edge weights in the matching is maximized. Now my question becomes: Does there exist an algorithm that outputs a maximum weight transveral and has a stable matching? Or is this still an open problem in graph theory to find such an algorithm?

Correct me if my explanation above about the Hungarian algorithm and Gale-Shapely algorithm is wrong, I am not a mathematics students.

Comment: What do you mean by _"Does there exist an algorithm that outputs a maximum weight transveral **and has a stable matching?**"_. In general, a maximum weighted matching need not be stable, so the two solutions are necessarily different. You have to pick which of the two best represents what you want

Comment: Yes so indeed as I understood a maximum weighted matching need not be stable. So suppose I would apply the Hungarian algorithm on a marriage problem. Where there are 5 men and 5 woman to be paired with each other where the edges represent the happiness of a men i and a woman j being paired with each other. Then the algorithm would output me a matching such that the sum of these weights is maximized, but the marriages not to be stable. So my question is, is there an algorithm that gives me a matching such that the it gives me a maximum weighted matching and is also a stable matching?

Comment: Why do you think such a matching exists?  Or are you asking for an algorithm that finds such a matching if one exists, and otherwise demonstrates that none exists?

Comment: So it has two give you **two different** solutions in general. Well, just run the Hungarian algorithm and then the Gale-Shapley algorithm

Comment: @salspatz I'm asking whether there exists an algorithm that finds me a matching M, such that M is a maximum weight matching and simultaneously stable.

Comment: In general you cannot have a matching which is **both** maximal and stable. You have to decide which property you prefer. Of course, you can compute both solutions and then decide which you like the best

Comment: @Federico That's what I thought indeed. But can you not have such a matching because it is mathematically impossible to have a matching that has a maximum weighted matching and is stable or didn't they manage yet to find such an algorithm that find such a matching?

Comment: I don't even see how the concept of stability applies here.  In the Gale-Shapely problem, the preferences of the men and women are not symmetric.  (John loves Mary best, but John is last on Mary's list.)  How is this expressed by a single weighted edge between Mary and John?

Comment: You cannot have an algorithm that does something impossible. Your requirement is not satisfiable in general

Comment: @Kroko it's mathematically impossible in general because there are examples where the maximal matchings are not stable

Comment: @saulspatz Can't I give the edges a weight value that is the combined value of the happiness of men i and women j. So for example (edge weight)ij=(happiness of men i)+(happiness of women j)=(edgeweight)42=12+4=16 for example if I pair men number 4 with women number 2?

Comment: @Federico Okey, thanks for answering! :)

Comment: You can do that if you like, but it doesn't model stability in the sense of Gale-Shapely.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes so I am not familiar with how the Gale-Shapely algorithimg works entirly, I should study that better. But thanks for answering. I was just wondering if there is a way to put the values and preferences of men i and woman j in a bipartite graph such that you would be able to come up with an algorithm that would give a maximum weight matching and is also stable. But I guess that is not possible then.